# Truth value of an array is ambiguous

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples A containing an array and a boolean value, and a sub list of it, B.
I'm trying to remove the sublists' elements from the main list, so im using:

```
    v1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    v2 = np.array([1, 2, 2])
    A = [(v1, True), (v2, False)]
    B = [(v1, True)]
    new_list = [x for x in A if x not in B]
```

I'm getting the following error:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

What truth values? And how will any() help here? i'm looking for tuples not booleans

Comment: can you post more code what is A and B

Comment: You have to share the list so that we can reproduce your problem

Comment: What is v1 and v2?

Comment: Based on my intuition, I'm pretty sure you want to use `(x not in B).any()`, but there's better ways to do it.

Comment: The code you've written doesn't produce the effect you've described. Please give us a full, runnable code segment that produces that error.

Comment: `if x not in B` is a boolean expression.  The `if` accepts only one True/False value.  The `x not in B` produces an array of True/False values.  Hence the ambiguity error.

Comment: @MadPhysicist it still gives the same error